# etherscan.io showing wrong balance for my Ethereum wallet

Tags: etherscan, balances

https://etherscan.io/address/0xdfd43138e27b98a73007618997c66ed6e9adb52f

So I almost have zero balance in this wallet (which is on an exchange if that matters), but it shows the balance as 0.43 ether. Is it a problem with etherscan website or I'm missing something?

Comment: No. There is no problem with etherscan. Maybe your exchange is not showing you correct balance. FYI there are other blockchain explorers like [etherchain](https://www.etherchain.org/account/DFd43138e27B98A73007618997c66Ed6e9adb52F) , [ethplorer](https://ethplorer.io/address/0xdfd43138e27b98a73007618997c66ed6e9adb52f) . You can check your balance, all of them show 0.43 ETH in your account

Comment: Is this wallet related to the exchange?

Comment: @Зелёный : as I mentioned in the question, yes

Comment: Do you have the private keys of that wallet? Or it is just an address which exchange give to you in order to deposit coins?

Answer (score 1):

If the exchange you're using is a centralized exchange, then this makes perfect sense. When you deposit coins to an exchange, the address they give you usually isn't *your* wallet, it's one of their collection wallets. They'll often sweep from these wallets when they get full enough and send the funds to their hot and/or cold wallets. They also usually don't send from the same wallet that they have you send to, so the balances of the address you send to usually wont match your balance on the exchanges internal ledger.

Comment: Does that mean that the exchange might share the address between multiple user? If yes, how do they determine which user the funds are being sent to when a deposit happens?

Comment: Usually, no. Most exchanges will have 1 address per user so the exchange knows who is trying to deposit when someone sends to that address.